# What is proper way to configure TinyMCE for handling image uploads, and what exactly is needed on the server-side handler?

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to integrate image uploads. I have the editor itself working except for that.

I already have the basic editor configured, but since there is no proper configuration for handling image uploads, or a backend image handling script, it's still just saving images in base64 in the database. That's not good for multiple reasons, including db bloat and it would mean sending out the full images with notifications of posts.

My question is about these two things:

(1) Help me understand what I'm supposed to configure when setting up the editor, as per the instructions here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/

(2) Help me better understand what I'm supposed to do for the backend script to accept the POST and return a success or failure and location of the saved image as explained in the PHP example here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/php-upload-handler/

I already had the basic editor configured, and I just dumped the code from the first link to initialize upload-images into it today. It didn't break anything, but since there is no backend it's still just saving images in base64 in the node. The only thing that changed is that it adds an "uploading progress" message that doesn't go away.

I don't know how to set the configurations correctly, and let it know not to save things unless the images are properly stored, etc.

Any more hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

To clarify, the current status is:

Whether images_upload_url: is defined or not, and whether first_image_upload_handler is there or not, if I choose the image uploader it uploads and saves as base64. If I choose the drag-and-drop dialog it hangs with a progress indicator that stays there forever.

Status update:

I have a dummy backend script running that returns a default image at the moment, and that works, and prevents the base64 from being saved in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Most of the code from the first link was not needed. On the backend, since I don't use PHP, I just needed to take the MIME header for the "file" form property being passed, create a unique filename as recommended and store it. Images are now being stored on the server and not in base64 in the database.